# Spring cloud client trying to run on server port 8888

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

The config server is up and the client is able to fetch the properties from config server.

```
HTTP GET http://localhost:8888/account-service/dev/config
Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
Response 200 OK
```

But the problem is, client service is trying to start on config server port 8888. I have set `server.port=8080` in the client but still not working.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8888 was already in use.
```

Am I missing any configuration here? Highly appreciate any help.

Config server application.properties,

```
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.cloud.config.profiles=dev 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=REPO_URL
server.port=8888
```

Comment: You should collect information about who is already using port 8888, then kill that service, and up this one again.

Comment: Please share your config server configuration

Comment: @JonathanJOhx config server is running on 8888

Comment: @spencergibb updated the question. Please check.

Comment: @VikasYadav Web server failed to start. Port 8888 was already in use. this happens when other service or app is using the port 8888, so first try to identify it and kill it and then lift the config server.

Comment: @JonathanJOhx I know. The service has port 8080, server.port=8080. So it should be starting on 8080, not 8888. And also, the issue with client service, not server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find the solution. When I was trying to start client service, `server.port` was also getting overridden with config server port. I added `server.port=8080` in the properties file for the client service profile in config repo (`account-service.properties`) and it worked.

Comment: saved me lot of time, thanks